# Laravel static create method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel since 5.1 and i've always been using `Model::create` method to create new DB record. Currently, i needed to dig into laravel API to find out the return type of that method (because i forgot that and also things could changed since the last time i was using Laravel framework).

So, when i was trying to find `static create(..)` method, i found out that the api docs for that method is missing since `5.3` version.

What is the reason of missing api docs for that method? Is it still safe to use static `create` method or it'll be deprecated?

Also, laravel docs missing information about nested controllers, which was in `laravel 5.2` and `5.3` docs...

Comment: The create method is in the 5.3 api docs : https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create

Comment: I believe they're asking about 5.4 and forward where there is not `create` method, not 5.3 and back where there is the `create` method. The question says it was in the 5.2 and 5.3 docs.

Comment: @Samsquanch I thought that might have been the case but I just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [upgrade docs for 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)

> **The create & forceCreate Methods**
>
> The `Model::create` & `Model::forceCreate` methods have been moved to the 
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class in order to provide better
>   support for creating models on multiple connections. However, if you
>   are extending these methods in your own models, you will need to
>   modify your implementation to call the `create` method on the builder.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> public static function create(array $attributes = [])
> {
>     $model = static::query()->create($attributes);
>
>     // ...
>
>     return $model;
> }
> ```